# JavaScript loop with anonymous function performance

Tags: javascript, performance

I have this simple code (the purpose of this code is irrelevant)

```js
const filter = function (object, subject, match) {
    const result = [];

    let index = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
        let existingIndex = -1;

        for (let j = index; j < subject.length; j++) {
            if (match(object[i], subject[j])) {
                existingIndex = j;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (existingIndex === -1) {
            result.push(object[i]);
        } else {
            index = existingIndex;
        }
    }

    return result;
};

const subjectArray = Array.from({ length: 199999 }).map((_, i) => i);
const objectArray1 = Array.from({ length: 99999 }).map((_, i) => i);
const objectArray2 = Array.from({ length: objectArray1.length }).map(() => -1);

const match = (item, entry) => item === entry;

function f1() {
    console.time("f1");

    filter(subjectArray, objectArray1, (item, entry) => item === entry);

    console.timeEnd("f1");
}

function f2() {
    console.time("f2");

    filter(subjectArray, objectArray2, (item, entry) => item === entry);

    console.timeEnd("f2");
}

f1();
f2();
```

When I run the code, it takes a lot of time. But when I change

`filter(subjectArray, objectArray2, (item, entry) => item === entry)`

to

`filter(subjectArray, objectArray2, match)`

the execution is much faster. Can somebody please explain to me, what is happening during the execution and what is the difference?

Comment: After reading the question properly, and more crucially *testing it* - behaviour reported just doesn't show up. Both `match` and the raw function seem to perform the same. I get somewhere between 58 and 65 seconds with the bigger dataset but that's with either of the two versions. The only difference shows up if both are called one after the other. Then *the second one* seems to take much longer - about three times as long around 170-180 seconds. However, it's literally "the second one called" that does it, not "the `match` version" or "the arrow function version".

Comment: Which engine did you test this with? In what environment did you run this? What numbers did you get?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the issue here is how JS engines optimize functions, but it has nothing to do with whether you pass in an arrow function directly or from a variable pointing to a function.

Instead, in your example, the difference comes from the order in which you call the `filter()` function.

Three disclaimers first:

- Optimization is done by the JS engine, so you will see different behavior on different engines
- I am in no way an expert on the topic, I want to share my findings to make it clear that **putting arrow functions into a variable has no impact on performance**.
- While fun and educational, unless you are doing high-performance computing where every microsecond counts, this should have next to no impact on the way you write code. Write for other programmers (including future you), not the compiler/interpreter.

So, why would execution order matter for performance? One of the tricks used by the optimizer is to inline functions. I basically means that the optimizer can replace calls to a function by their implementation.

So the second function here:

```
const square = (x) => x*x
const doubleSquare = (x) => 2*square(x)
```

can be internally optimized into the same as:

```
const doubleSquare = (x) => 2*x*x
```

This even happens when the function is passed in. A call like this:

```
const doubleFun = (x, fun) => 2*fun(x)
doubleFun(3, square)
```

can trigger an optimization where the stored version of `doubleFun()` is inlined with the supplied function, turning it effectively into the same as above:

```
const doubleFun = (x, fun) => 2*x*x*
```

However, if you then call the function with a different callback (say `doubleFun(3, Math.sign)`) the optimizer has to go back, remove the old inlined function and add the new one. This process is called deoptimization, and it takes some time. This is what happens in your code, and why it seems like the second run (which coincidentally was the version with the inlined arrow function in your case) takes longer than the first.

---

You can actually observe the process in node, which uses Google's V8 engine. It outputs optimization and deoptimization notifications with the `--trace-opt` and `--trace-deopt` flag respectively.

I am using your `filter()` function and call them with these functions:

```
const match = (item, entry) => item === entry;

function withPointer() {
    console.time("withPointer");
    filter(subjectArray, objectArray, match);
    console.timeEnd("withPointer");
}

function withInline() {
    console.time("withInline");
    filter(subjectArray, objectArray, (item, entry) => item === entry);
    console.timeEnd("withInline");
}

console.log('GO pointer')
withPointer()

console.log('GO inline')
withInline()
```

When I run it with `--trace-opt`, I get this for `withInline()`:

```
GO inline
[found optimized code for 0x35b29fbc2ab1 <JSFunction filter (sfi = 0x38454569b381)> (target TURBOFAN) at OSR bytecode offset 102]
[compiling method 0x35b29fbc2ab1 <JSFunction filter (sfi = 0x38454569b381)> (target TURBOFAN) using Turbofan OSR]
[optimizing 0x35b29fbc2ab1 <JSFunction filter (sfi = 0x38454569b381)> (target TURBOFAN) - took 0.013, 2.027, 0.026 ms]
[marking 0x354e9b6c2051 <JSFunction (sfi = 0x3845456aaaf1)> for optimization to TURBOFAN, ConcurrencyMode::kConcurrent, reason: small function]
[compiling method 0x354e9b6c2051 <JSFunction (sfi = 0x3845456aaaf1)> (target TURBOFAN) using Turbofan]
[optimizing 0x354e9b6c2051 <JSFunction (sfi = 0x3845456aaaf1)> (target TURBOFAN) - took 0.006, 0.398, 0.011 ms]
[completed optimizing 0x354e9b6c2051 <JSFunction (sfi = 0x3845456aaaf1)> (target TURBOFAN)]
```

Ignoring the marker, you can see that it first optimizes the already known `filter()` function in the first three lines, and then optimizes an unnamed function in the last four lines. This is the inlined function, which is optimized just the same as the one in `match` (you can observe that the same way, I omit it here for brevity).

Allow me to emphasize again: Anonymous functions are optimized just the same as other functions.

---

Now lets run the whole thing with the `--trace-deopt` flag. Output is:

```
GO pointer
[bailout (kind: deopt-eager, reason: Insufficient type feedback for generic named access): begin. deoptimizing 0x28cb5c092131 <JSFunction filter (sfi = 0x3137cc314e49)>, opt id 2, bytecode offset 69, deopt exit 1, FP to SP delta 168, caller SP 0x7fffdc01a3a0, pc 0x000006bd6cd2]
withPointer: 213.071ms
GO inline
[bailout (kind: deopt-eager, reason: wrong call target): begin. deoptimizing 0x361b02a4ced1 <JSFunction filter (sfi = 0x3137cc314e49)>, opt id 3, bytecode offset 7, deopt exit 14, FP to SP delta 176, caller SP 0x7fffdc01a3a0, pc 0x000006bd7376]
withInline: 304.591ms
```

I don't know what the first message means, but you can see that when running the second time, deoptimization is running.

Let's turn it around and run the inline version before the pointer one:

```
GO inline
[bailout (kind: deopt-eager, reason: Insufficient type feedback for generic named access): begin. deoptimizing 0x1f1dddbd4561 <JSFunction filter (sfi = 0x30b415014f89)>, opt id 2, bytecode offset 69, deopt exit 1, FP to SP delta 168, caller SP 0x7ffe072c3630, pc 0x000006116cd2]
withInline: 209.497ms
GO pointer
[bailout (kind: deopt-eager, reason: wrong call target): begin. deoptimizing 0x20ca6714d511 <JSFunction filter (sfi = 0x30b415014f89)>, opt id 3, bytecode offset 7, deopt exit 14, FP to SP delta 176, caller SP 0x7ffe072c3630, pc 0x000006117376]
withPointer: 308.85ms
```

Same as before, first run is faster, second run includes a deoptimization step.

The difference does not come from inline vs pointer, it's the order in which you run the function.

---

Finally, let's see if we can create an optimized version beforehand by calling `filter(subjectArray, objectArray, (item, entry) => item === entry);` before calling the functions:

```
filter(subjectArray, objectArray, (item, entry) => item === entry);

console.log('GO pointer')
withPointer()

console.log('GO inline')
withInline()
```

And indeed it gives us:

```
[bailout (kind: deopt-eager, reason: Insufficient type feedback for generic named access): begin. deoptimizing 0x2b78d108bbc9 <JSFunction filter (sfi = 0x2826d0ed4f91)>, opt id 2, bytecode offset 69, deopt exit 1, FP to SP delta 168, caller SP 0x7ffc7a52db90, pc 0x000006216352]
GO pointer
[bailout (kind: deopt-eager, reason: wrong call target): begin. deoptimizing 0x11a825c8b6d1 <JSFunction filter (sfi = 0x2826d0ed4f91)>, opt id 3, bytecode offset 7, deopt exit 14, FP to SP delta 176, caller SP 0x7ffc7a52db30, pc 0x000006217136]
withPointer: 307.842ms
GO inline
withInline: 266.868ms
```

So now the deoptimization happens at the first call, while the second one runs without interruption and is faster than the first.

And with two calls above the functions, no de-optimization happens during the functions, and we get pretty much the same runtime:

```
[bailout (kind: deopt-eager, reason: Insufficient type feedback for generic named access): begin. deoptimizing 0x0f7ddc811c99 <JSFunction filter (sfi = 0x104e5ad4f99)>, opt id 2, bytecode offset 69, deopt exit 1, FP to SP delta 168, caller SP 0x7ffc177e6eb0, pc 0x000006916352]
[bailout (kind: deopt-eager, reason: wrong call target): begin. deoptimizing 0x034c393079a9 <JSFunction filter (sfi = 0x104e5ad4f99)>, opt id 3, bytecode offset 7, deopt exit 14, FP to SP delta 176, caller SP 0x7ffc177e6eb0, pc 0x000006917136]
GO pointer
withPointer: 266.525ms
GO inline
withInline: 263.062ms
```

This also gives us a rough idea of the different runtime of optimized code, deoptimized code and deoptimization itself:

| Run | Duration [ms] |
| --- | --- |
| Optimized `filter()` | 206 |
| Deoptimized `filter()` | 265 |
| Deoptimization | 307 - 265 = 42 |

Considering how in your initial example, if you got similar numbers that I did, the second call took around 50% longer than the first, it makes sense to wonder. The second call takes more time because it has to deoptimize the `filter()` function and run deoptimized code.

---

Sorry for the long post, but I think it is really important not to take the wrong lesson from a (very good) observation like yours. I hope the observations show that it is not the way you use arrow functions what determines performance here. Try it out yourself, let me know if your findings match mine.

Comment: +1                                                         for the disclaimers alone, I hadn't even read the rest

Comment: "*This [is] deoptimization, and it takes some time.*" - not just that, but also the less-optimised code is simply slower